# Sequelize ORM - Error: not returning database values

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm try to return a password from database to another javascript file. The function will retrieve the data correctly. But when I return the value to another function, it will be changed to undefined. I want to return a password from `model.js` to `controller.js`.

code : 
model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); //import sequelize orm

// connect with psql db
var connection = new Sequelize('emd','postgres','test',{
  dialect : 'postgres'
});

//create a table;
var student = connection.define('student',{
  name : {
    type : Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull : false},
  email : {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique : true,
    allowNull : false},
  password : {
    type : Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull : false },
  mobile : {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT(11),
    unique : true,
    allowNull : false }
});

var methods = {};
  methods.signup = function(u_name,u_email,u_password,u_mobile){
      connection.sync().then(function(){
        student.create({
          name : u_name,
          email : u_email,
          password : u_email,
          mobile : u_mobile
        });
      });
    }
  methods.login = function(email_id){

    connection.sync().then(function(){
        student.findOne({where : {email : email_id }} ).then(results =>{
          return results.dataValues.password;    
        });
      });
    }

exports.fun = methods;
```

code: Controller.js

```
var model = require('./model.js')

var methods={}
  methods.login = function(email,password){
    let res = model.fun.login(email)
    console.log(res);
    if(password===res){
      console.log("success");
    }
    else {
      console.log("failure");
    }
  }


exports.cont = methods
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add on to @Sagar Jojoriya,

Change your model.js like this

```
methods.login = function(email_id, callbackFun){
connection.sync().then(function(){
    student.findOne({where : {email : email_id }} ).then(results =>{
      console.log("debug pass => ", results.dataValues.password);
      callbackFun(results.dataValues.password);
    });
  });
}
```

And in your controller.js

```
methods.login = function(email,password){
    model.fun.login(email, function(resPassword) {
        if(password === resPassword){
        console.log("success");
    } else {
      console.log("failure");
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I got error like this : `Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: callbackFun is not defined`

Comment: `console.log("debug pass => ", results.dataValues.password);`
is this line printed ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the function `model.fun.login` is asynchronous so before getting response from this function, it'll move to the next statement, which returns `undefined`.

```
methods.login = function(email,password){
    model.fun.login(email, function(resPassword) {
        if(password === resPassword){
          console.log("success");
        }
        else {
          console.log("failure");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I cant't understand. Can you  explain?

Comment: Where I get response value?

Answer (score 0):

You can return the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and handle it in `then` block inside `controller`.

```
reutrn student.findOne({where : {email : email_id }} ));
```

This will return the promise. In the controller, you can call the method as

```
model.fun.login(email).then(function(result){
    console.log(JSON.stringfy(result));
});
```

Comment: It shows error like this.. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.methods.login (/home/dinesh/EMD/server/controller.js:6:27)`